# Funnel Algorithm finding the optimal path through a polygon

Tags: algorithm, polygon, shortest-path

I would like to get the shortest path through a polygon. My inputs are a start point, a destination point and a list of vertices of my polygon. 
I was searching the web and I found following sites describing the Funnel algorithm:
[1](http://ahamnett.blogspot.co.at/2012/10/funnel-algorithm.html), [2](http://digestingduck.blogspot.co.uk/2010/03/simple-stupid-funnel-algorithm.html), [3](https://skatgame.net/mburo/ps/thesis_demyen_2006.pdf). 
I tried to implement the algorithm from number [3](https://skatgame.net/mburo/ps/thesis_demyen_2006.pdf). But there are many questions coming up to understand the listing right. I do not know which angle has to be calculated in function Add. 
I do not know what the FunnelDeque ApexType is. 
So my questions are: Exists there an easy implementation of this Funnel Algorithm? 
If no, how can I implement the Algorithm from [3](https://skatgame.net/mburo/ps/thesis_demyen_2006.pdf), getting an useable result.

Comment: If you have a list of vertices, a start point and a destination point, isn't this just a shortest path graph problem? Do you really need to use a Funnel Algorithm?

Comment: Yes I need the Funnel Algorithm to solve the problem. Because The vertices are only describing the polygon borders. Therefore I do not know how to "walk" through the polygon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was possible to solve this issue by using the shortest path algorithm. It was only necessary to convert the polygon into nodes.